# Alamofire throws a fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift, alamofire, option-type

Please help, I'm very new to Swift. The API call from the search bar works fine if I perform it once. However, when I clear the Search Bar and try again, I get this error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

at this line:

```
mutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: URLString.URLString)!)
```

Here is my code. Please help:

```
    // Functions for adding search
func createSearchBar() {
    searchBar.placeholder = "Anchor Steam"
    searchBar.delegate = self

    // put into navigation bar
    self.navigationItem.titleView = searchBar
}

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    makeAPICall(searchBar.text!)
}

func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    self.searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
    searchBar.text = ""
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    self.searchResultTableView.reloadData()
}
func makeAPICall(beer: String) {
    print("THE SEARCHED BEER IS \(beer)")
     Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://api.untappd.com/v4/search/beer?q=\(beer)&client_id=AAA&client_secret=AAA").responseJSON { response in
            if let json = response.result.value {
                print ("Connection to API successful!")
                if let secondJSON = json["response"] as! NSDictionary? {
                    if let beersJSON = secondJSON["beers"] as! NSDictionary? {
                        if let beerItems = beersJSON["items"] as! [NSDictionary]? {
                            var beersJsonArray: [NSDictionary] = []
                            for beerObject in beerItems {
                                let insideBeerHash = beerObject["beer"]
                                beersJsonArray.append(insideBeerHash as! NSDictionary)
                            }

                            self.beers = Beer.convertBeers((beersJsonArray as? [NSDictionary]!)!)
                            self.searchResultTableView.reloadData()

                        }
                    }
                }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Since you are new to Swift read the chapter about the basics (especially optionals) in the Swift Language Guide. The syntax `if let ... as! Foo?` is absurd.

Comment: Thank you @vadian. I read on optionals and it's working now!

Answer (score 0):

Options:

1) Be sure **URLString.URLString** is defined

2) If it is try with: let url:

**let mutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(string: URLString.URLString)!**

3) Or maybe:

**let mutableURLRequest = NSURL(string: URLString.URLString)!**